# Get the data of particular area with given miles

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to calculate the Listings that is near to  city with given miles. Suppose I have one area **xyzArea** and in this area i have particular latitude and longitude also and in some distance of 1 miles there is 5 more listings. I want to get that 5 listings. when user click on 1 miles. can anyone help me how to achieve this functionality. Any helpful link must commented. I am using laravel 5.2 framework Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any code blocks or you don't know how to even start?

Comment: this is my client requirement i have not yet started but rest of searching i have doen expect miles seraching he want searching like treatwell.co.uk

Comment: Computers can help with that

Comment: oh really :p @Strawberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT
    `id`,
    (
        6371 *
        acos(
            cos( radians( :lat ) ) *
            cos( radians( `lat` ) ) *
            cos(
                radians( `long` ) - radians( :long )
            ) +
            sin(radians(:lat)) *
            sin(radians(`lat`))
        )
    ) `distance`
FROM
    `location`
HAVING
    `distance` < :distance
ORDER BY
    `distance`
LIMIT
    25

Hope that helps you
Thanks

Comment: where is miles in query ?

Comment: The distance  variable

Comment: Hope that blog will help you  http://our-knowledge-base.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-search-within-defined-radius.html

Comment: Here the updated QuerySELECT
  id, (
    3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(78.3232) )
      * cos( radians( lat ) )
      * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(65.3234) )
      + sin ( radians(78.3232) )
      * sin( radians( lat ) )
    )
  ) AS distance
FROM markers
HAVING distance < 30
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;   Here 30 is distance

Comment: 30 is miles or km please clear once?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is not a framework specific question, rather a database-related one. All you need is store the location of the listings, and query the ones that are within the given range. As db engines do not have this feature by default you have to use 3rd party plugins like PostGIS for PostgreSQL(I'm sure there are plugins for other db-s). Also you will have to add a new datatype for Doctrine as it does not have it by default.

Comment: according to you we have to create our own logic to implement this type of searching

Comment: partly. the plugin gives all the functionality, you only have to write the queries for it. like 
SELECT * FROM <table> t WHERE ST_Distance(the_geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100000 200000)', 312)) < 100
but if you use Doctrine you will have to extend it - but that should not be a problem

Comment: firstly i have to install plugin that i have no knowledge about that plugin how to use. I think i want to find some other solution with core query

Comment: you can write all the logic yourself, BUT it will take a lot of time, and the performance will not even near the plugins'. These plugins were created for these type of applications, well documented and have nice performance. But you know what you want